# uploadFile function in Dropbox api returns nothing after uploading new file

Tags: php, wordpress, dropbox-api

i am facing issue regarding to upload file in dropbox via php.Actually i am using uploadFile function.This function supposed to return the meta data of newly uploaded file after uploading file.But in my case it returns nothing and browser throws 504 gateway timing error.But file uploads successfully.I am using this code.

```
echo 'Sending file to DropBox';
$appInfo = dbx\AppInfo::loadFromJsonFile(ABSPATH."wp-content/plugins/wp-cloud-safe/lib/app-info.json");
$webAuth = new dbx\WebAuthNoRedirect($appInfo, "PHP-Example/1.0");
        $filename=ABSPATH.'clients.webkitmedia.com_dfd_16th-February-2016-10:43.zip';
$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($this->dropboxGeneratedAccessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");

//print_r($dbxClient);
$f = fopen($filename,'rb');
//$filesize=filesize($filename);
$reult= $dbxClient->uploadFile('/test/testing.zip', dbx\WriteMode::add(),$f);
print_r($reult);
die();
fclose($f);
```

Please suggest any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I replace these lines in upper code and issue get resolved.

```
$f = file_get_contents($filename);
$reult= $dbxClient->uploadFileFromString('/test/testing.zip', dbx\WriteMode::add(),$f);
```